# Jquery valores dependientes en varias filas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Tengo un botón que agrega, por un lado una fila en una tabla con campos para llenar.
También, con el mismo botón, se agrega una fila en otra tabla, donde se completan algunos datos dependientes de la primera tabla.
El problema es que al agregar dos filas o más, los datos dependientes sólo se replican en la primera fila de la segunda tabla.

Aquí el código:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add").click(function(){
cant = $('#contador-filas').val();
cant++;
// Obtenemos el numero de columnas (td) que tiene la primera fila
// (tr) del id "tabla"
var tds=$("#servicio tr:first td").length;
var tds=$("#TablaCadete tr:first td").length;
// Obtenemos el total de filas (tr) del id "tabla"
var trs=$("#servicio tr").length;
var trs=$("#TablaCadete tr").length;
var nuevaFila="<tr id='"+(cant)+"'>";
var nuevaFilaCadete="<tr id='"+(cant)+"'>";


$('#contador-filas').val(cant)
nuevaFila+="<td><input class='form-control' id='servicio_cantidad' name='servicio_cantidad["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='Cantidad"+(cant)+"' size='5' type='text' value='1' onBlur='Calcular(this);' required /> </td>"+
"<td><?php include ("includes/conexion.php"); $resultServicios = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listasyservicios WHERE id_listadeprecios = '$ListaDePreciosSucursal' ORDER BY id_listasyservicios ASC"); ?><select id='servicio_desc' name='servicio_desc["+(cant)+"]' class='form-control custom-select' onBlur='Calcular(this);'><option value=''>-Seleccione Servicio-</option><?php while($rowServicio= mysql_fetch_object($resultServicios)){echo "<option value=".$rowServicio->id_listasyservicios.">";echo "".$rowServicio->id_servicio." - ".$rowServicio->nombreservicio."</option>";} ?></select></td>"+

"<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='servicio_preciounitario' name='servicio_preciounitario["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' onBlur='Calcular(this);' required /> </td>"+

"<td><input class='form-control totalservicio' type='text' id='servicio_preciototal' name='servicio_preciototal["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' readonly /> </td>"+

"<td><div id='del' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Eliminar</div></td>";

nuevaFila+="</tr>";

$("#servicio").append(nuevaFila);


nuevaFilaCadete+="<td><input class='form-control' id='cod_cadete' name='cod_cadete["+(cant)+"]' value='<?php echo ''.$Asignado_Id_Empleado.''; ?>' size='5' type='text' required /> </td>"+
"<td><?php include ("includes/conexion.php"); $resultCadete = mysql_query("SELECT id_empleado, apellido, nombre FROM empleados WHERE id_puesto = 11 ORDER BY id_empleado ASC"); ?><select id='cadete_desc' name='cadete_desc["+(cant)+"]' class='form-control custom-select'><option value=''>-Seleccione Cadete-</option><?php while($rowCadete= mysql_fetch_object($resultCadete)){echo "<option value=".$rowCadete->id_empleado.""; if($Asignado_Id_Empleado==$rowCadete->id_empleado){echo " selected";}; echo">";echo "".$rowCadete->id_empleado." - ".$rowCadete->apellido.", ".$rowCadete->nombre."</option>";} ?></select></td>"+

"<td><input class='form-control' id='servicio_cantidad_cadete' name='servicio_cantidad_cadete["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='Cantidad"+(cant)+"' size='5' type='text' value='1' onBlur='Calcular(this);' required /> </td>"+
"<td><?php include ("includes/conexion.php"); $resultServicios = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listasyservicios WHERE id_listadeprecios = '$ListaDePreciosSucursal' ORDER BY id_listasyservicios ASC"); ?><select id='servicio_desc_cadete' name='servicio_desc_cadete["+(cant)+"]' class='form-control custom-select' onBlur='Calcular(this);'><option value=''>-Seleccione Servicio-</option><?php while($rowServicio= mysql_fetch_object($resultServicios)){echo "<option value=".$rowServicio->id_listasyservicios.">";echo "".$rowServicio->id_servicio." - ".$rowServicio->nombreservicio."</option>";} ?></select></td>"+

"<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='servicio_preciounitario_cadete' name='servicio_preciounitario_cadete["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' onBlur='Calcular(this);' required /> </td>"+

"<td><input class='form-control totalservicio' type='text' id='servicio_preciototal_cadete' name='servicio_preciototal_cadete["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' readonly /> </td>"+

"<td><div id='del' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Eliminar</div></td>";

nuevaFilaCadete+="</tr>";

$("#TablaCadete").append(nuevaFilaCadete);

});

});


$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#del', function (event) {
  var total = document.getElementById('TotalServicios');
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) - parseFloat(this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].value);
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  
  Calcular(event.target);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#servicio_cantidad").blur(function () {
              var value = $(this).val();
              $("#servicio_cantidad_cadete").val(value);
          });
      });



$(function () {
$('#servicio').on('change', 'select', function() {
  
  var servicioVal = $(this).val(); 

  //petición ajax
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actioncomboServiciosEnRemitos.php",
    dataType: "json",

    data: { "servicioVal" : servicioVal },
    async : false,
    success: function(respuesta){
 preciounitario =  respuesta[0]; 
 preciocosto =  respuesta[1]; 
 servId =  servicioVal;
}
 
 
  });

  var $nextInput = $(this).closest("td").next().find("input:text");
  $nextInput.val(preciounitario);  
  var $ServicioIdCadetes = $("#servicio_desc_cadete").closest("td").find("select");
  $ServicioIdCadetes.val(servId);  
  var $PrecioUnitarioCadetes = $("#servicio_preciounitario_cadete").closest("td").find("input:text");
  $PrecioUnitarioCadetes.val(preciocosto);  

});
});

function Calcular(ele) {
            var cantidad = 0, precunit = 0, totalitem = 0 ;
   
            var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
            var nodes = tr.childNodes;
        
            for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
               
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == "servicio_cantidad") {
                    cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == "servicio_preciounitario") {
                    precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == "servicio_preciototal") {
                    anterior = nodes[x].firstChild.value;
                    totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
                    nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem;
    }
    if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == "servicio_cantidad_cadete") {
                    cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == "servicio_preciounitario_cadete") {
                    precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == "servicio_preciototal_cadete") {
                    anterior = nodes[x].firstChild.value;
                    totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
                    nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem; 
     
     
    if (totalitem.innerHTML == "NaN") {
                totalitem.innerHTML = 0;
                // 
            }
                }
            }
             calcular_total();   
        }


function calcular_total() {
 importe_total = 0
 $("#servicio .totalservicio").each(
  function(index, value) {
   importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
  }
 );
 var importe_totalEntero = importe_total; 
 var importe_total2Dec = importe_totalEntero.toFixed(2); 
 $("#TotalServiciosTabla #TotalServiciosInput").val(importe_total2Dec);
 $("#TotalServiciosTabla #TotalServicios").html(importe_total2Dec);
}
  
  
</script>
```

```html
<table id="servicio">
      <thead id="borrarAncla">
        <tr>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Servicio</th>
    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th><div id="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Agregar</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>


<tbody>
<input type="hidden" id="contador-filas" value="0"> 
<?
   
   $resultServ = mysql_query("SELECT serviciosenremitos.id_servicioenremito, serviciosenremitos.id_remito, serviciosenremitos.id_servicio FROM serviciosenremitos WHERE serviciosenremitos.id_remito = '$idRemito' ORDER BY serviciosenremitos.id_servicioenremito ASC "); 
   
   if ($rowServicios= mysql_fetch_array($resultServ)){ 
   do { 
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td><input name="servicio_cantidad" class="form-control" id="servicio_cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad" size="10" type="text" value="Cantidad"></td>';
   echo '<td><input name="servicio_desc" class="form-control" id="servicio_desc" placeholder="Servicio" size="15" type="text" value="'.$rowServicios["id_servicio"].'"></td>';
   echo '<td><input name="servicio_preciounitario" class="form-control" id="servicio_preciounitario" placeholder="0,00" size="10" type="text"></td>';
   echo '<td><input name="servicio_preciototal" class="form-control" id="servicio_preciototal" placeholder="0,00" size="10" type="text" ></td>';
   echo '</tr>';
   } while ($rowServicios = mysql_fetch_array($resultServ)); 
   } else { 
   echo 'No hay servicios cargados para este remito.'; 
   }
   ?>
</tbody>
       </table>
<table id="TotalServiciosTabla">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <th>TOTAL $</th>
       <td><div id="TotalServicios" style="text-align:right;font-weight: bold;"> <input class="form-control" id="TotalServiciosInput" type="hidden" >
       </div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
       </table>
</div>
<div class="form-title">

<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="Prestador">Prestador</label> 
<input type="hidden" name="CodPrestador" class="form-control" id="CodPrestador"> 
<select name="Prestador" id="Prestador" class="form-control">
<?php
   $resultAsignado_Id_Empleado = mysql_query("SELECT id_empleado, apellido, nombre FROM empleados WHERE id_puesto = 11 ORDER BY id_empleado ASC  
        "); 
        
   if ($rowAsignado_Id_Empleado = mysql_fetch_array($resultAsignado_Id_Empleado)){ 
   do { 
   echo '<option value="'.$rowAsignado_Id_Empleado["id_empleado"].'"';
   if($Asignado_Id_Empleado==$rowAsignado_Id_Empleado["id_empleado"]){echo 'selected';};
   echo '>';
   echo ''.$rowAsignado_Id_Empleado["id_empleado"].' - '.$rowAsignado_Id_Empleado["apellido"].', '.$rowAsignado_Id_Empleado["nombre"].'</option>';
   
   }
   while ($rowAsignado_Id_Empleado = mysql_fetch_array($resultAsignado_Id_Empleado)); 
   } else { 
   echo 'No hay Cadetes.'; 
   }
   ?>
</select>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="w3l-table-info">
<table id="TablaCadete">
      <thead>
        <tr>
       <th>Cod. Cadete</th>
       <th>Apellido y Nombre</th>
       <th>Cantidad</th>
       <th>Descripci&oacute;n</th>
       <th>Precio Unitario</th>
       <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
       </table>
<table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <th>TOTAL</th>
       <td><div style="text-align:right;font-weight: bold;"> $ XXXXX</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
       </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Usas ids de números `id="1"` en alguna parte de tu pagina o sobre todo en algunas de las tablas?

Comment: Si. Cada fila que se agrega tiene un id. Y coinciden en ambas tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer esa usar justamente las ids que generas cuando agregas un `tr` para poder vincular la funcionalidad con otro mismo `tr` de la  otra tabla.
Al ser tu ejemplo  muy grande y estar en php te dejo un ejemplo mínimo para que entiendas la lógica que propongo.

```js
var cant = 0;
$("#load").click(function() {
  cant++;
  var tr = '<tr id="' + cant + '">' +
    '<td>' + cant + '</td><td><select> ' +
    '<option value="1">Uno</option>' +
    '<option value="2">Dos</option>' +
    '<option value="3">Tres</option>' +
    '</select></td></tr>';
  var tr2 = '<tr id="' + cant + '">' +
    '<td>' + cant + '</td><td><select id="servicio_desc_cadete"> ' +
    '<option value="1">Prueba 1</option>' +
    '<option value="2">Prueba 2</option>' +
    '<option value="3">Prueba 3</option>' +
    '</select></td></tr>';

  $("#servicio").append(tr);
  $("#TablaCadete").append(tr2);

});

$("#servicio").on("change", "select", function() {

  // en esta funcion primero ubica al tr padre para hacer el cambio en el elemento
  // asi no se cruzara el  elemento que buscas
  //obetnemos el valor
  var value = $(this).val();
  //obtenemos el tr padre para tener el id generado y usarlo en la otra tabla
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();  
  var id = tr.attr("id");

  //console.log(id);
  
  ///cambias la linea 
  //  var $ServicioIdCadetes = $("#servicio_desc_cadete").closest("td").find("select");
  //porla siguiente que busca en tu tabla el id para despues buscar el select
  var select = $("#TablaCadete").find("#"+ id).find("#servicio_desc_cadete");

  select.val(value);
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="load">Agregar</button>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<table id="servicio" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<table id="TablaCadete" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Input</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
</table>
```